# Which version of windows to download for a serial code

Tags: windows, windows-xp, serial, licensing

I have a serial code of a Windows XP (it is on the case), but i do not know which version of Windows to download. How could i find out from the running system which version should I download? Because I have tried some win XP cd and the serial wasn't accepted with the verison. Does it matter if I have OEM or other version? or how is it.

Thank you

Comment: It does matter. Either ask your IT department. Or if you are the corp. admin, wonder why your documentation is lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is on the case it will b a OEM license ... It should say on that sticker for e.g. Windows XP professional or home or which ever edition. The serial may be your machine service tag if it does not mention the os version.

Normally with oem one gets the media included with the pc or if it is still under warranty you can call your vendor.

If there is a operating system running on it like xp you can check the version / edition by "right click COMPUTER > then properties"

Hope this helps